# How to write this math equation in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode

I want insert this math equation into my paper:

[image: Math rockz!]

However, the part in the brackets make me confused. I google math equation in LaTeX but find no relavent information. This is what I alreadly have now:

```
$MR(e) = \Pi_{(R_{i}.ID, R_{j}.ID)}()$
```

[image]

Could you please help me to fill in the brackets.

Comment: Please try to specify your problem (and edit the title accordingly). Are you struggling with any of the symbols? Then have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol. Is it the putting text on top of other text? Then specify that, please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, never use `$\Pi$` when you obviously mean `$\prod$`. Second, I guess dots here between `$R_i$` and `$ID$` should be centered.

Here is what I got:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Dist}{Dist}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{displaymath}
  MR(e) = \prod_{(R_i\cdot ID, R_j\cdot ID)}
  \underset{\Dist_{sp}(r_i,r_j)\le\delta}{(R_i\bowtie R_j)} 
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am appreciate for your help. One more question, do you know how to add this into a algorithm after \state(I use algorithms package). I know how to insert use $ $ method, but don't know how to use \begin{dispalymath} \end{dispalymath}

Comment: Use this: `$MR(e) = \prod_{(R_i\cdot ID, R_j\cdot ID)} \underset{\Dist_{sp}(r_i,r_j)\le\delta}{(R_i\bowtie R_j)}$`.  Note that the expression under `\prod` symbol becomes inline rather than under it:  this is because you move from display math to inline math.